# Vue3 Transparent component wrapper not working

Tags: vue.js

I am testing out vue3 and wanted to make a transparent wrapper component (something I will use fairly often) with the new version. With the new syntax it should be as simple `v-bind="attrs"`. This does not seem to be working for me however and there is not much documentation as of yet. Anyone know what the problem could be? See codepen for more details as to how I am implementing it as well.

https://codepen.io/sumcoding/pen/mdJqwgj

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if codepen is a good place to reproduce this since I don't know how to make an import -> `import { reactive } from "vue";` so your `myValue` would be reactive.

Anyway I have got it working using `<input v-model="attrs.modelValue">`.

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/RwPjJLr?editors=1010)

BTW
Since you have registered `props`, you don't need to return them in a `setup` method ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This gets closer to the expected result, the value gets updated in the child component when the parent component changes, but the child component still cant seem to update the value. 

`const { reactive } = Vue;` is whats needed for an import in this case, but reactive does not help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The transparent wrapper component pattern for Vue.js 3 final can be implemented  like this

```
<template>
  <label>{{ label }}</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    :value="modelValue"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'InputWrapper',
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue']
};
</script>
```

You can view an example as well as another variation of the pattern for Vue.js 3 [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/transparent-input-wrapper-in-vuejs-3-ml3hb?file=/src/App.vue).